# Why would an IBM netvista suddenly fail to turn on?

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, power, desktop

I have an old Pentium IBM Netvista desktop PC with I believe an ATX power supply. For reference, the cable going into the motherboard from the power is 10 pins long by 2 wide and the info on the power supply is:

```
IBM part #: 24P6880
IBM FRU # 24P6883
```

The last time I used the PC was about 3 months ago. Back then when I turned the power on from the house power supply (monitor power was also connected to the house supply) the fans started going for 3 seconds then shut off then I press the power button once and everything turns on normally.

Now (3 months later) I do the same thing again (exactly same setup as before), except this time when I turn the power on from the same house supply (same voltage and all), the monitor turns on, but the desktop does not. I may have been lucky one time when I turned the power off and on a few random seconds later but when I did manage to turn it on, I got a few random beeps and the system gave an error. I was able to run setup at that point and save settings, but after exiting setup, the screen goes blank. So I turned the power off, then shortly after, I tried turning it on again 10 times in a row with about 30 seconds break in-between and nothing in the desktop wanted to turn on. No fan, nothing. I then begin to unplug all the peripherals except motherboard and tried again, and still nothing.

Could this all be a power supply thing?

Only thing I didn't try which is taped up when I got it was the voltage selector switch on the back of the supply. Do you think that would help? what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I then decided to take the power supply out of the PC to see whats wrong with it, and when I did a continuity test on a power connector, it turned out everything was short-circuited (aka 12V, 5V and ground were electrically all connected together).

So now I'm gonna replace the supply and pray for the best.